# Create custom view group of LineaLayout in android

Tags: android, layout

I want to create a common class for the profile picture which should have 2 ImageViews in it and should load from the remote URLs.

I've placed Image view many at many places in my project so now I need to update it all the places so I'm thinking to create to LinearLayout widget so I can update it in the place of the Image view and later on the future I can update it centrally if needed.

Here is my existing layout

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivAboutProfilePic"
            style="@style/ImageViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_profilepic_menu"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_profilepic_menu"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_user_default"
            app:riv_border_color="@color/orange_dark"
            app:riv_border_width="1dp"
            app:riv_corner_radius="@dimen/size_profilepic_menu"
            app:riv_oval="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivProfileBadge"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_minus2sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_minus5sdp"
            android:rotation="335"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pro_crown_yelloworange" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I need to update it with a custom class.

Please help me on this.

Comment: not sure I understand, you are trying to be able to update all the images at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivAboutProfilePic"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivProfileBadge"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:rotation="335"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cross" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

JpCustomView.java

```
public class JpCustomView extends RelativeLayout {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ImageView ivAboutProfilePic;
private Context context;

public JpCustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    init();

}

public JpCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    init();

}

public void init() {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.demo, this, true);
    ivAboutProfilePic = view.findViewById(R.id.ivAboutProfilePic);

}

public void loadImage(String url) {
    if (ivAboutProfilePic != null) {
        /*Your Code For Loading Image From Url*/

    }

}
}
```

In your xml

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/app_gray">

        <com.pms.activity.customviews.JpCustomView
            android:id="@+id/jpCustomView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp" />



    </RelativeLayout>
```

In your java file

```
JpCustomView  jpCustomView = findViewById(R.id.jpCustomView);
jpCustomView.loadImage("remote url here");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write BaseActivity OR BaseFragment which extends all your activity containing mentioned ImageViews.

After Extending Activity/Fragment you can write code in BaseActivity and BaseFragment in onResum method for fetching image from remote url. and in same way overriding that method in you activity you can set image after downloading completed.
Please feel free to ask if anything on this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but Instead using 2 views I need to combine both views in single linear layout and use that widget. 

The purpose of making view group is I'm also using profile picture in list view and recycler view so it will not help me there.